# Google app script upload image to Amazon S3 using signature and policy return body is not well-formed multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-s3, google-apps-script, postman

I'm creating an automation tool to upload my images to Amazon S3 with a given policy, signature and other parameters. I can perform this request easily on Postman or Insomnia but it seems really hard to get it done with code. I've tried some python code too, but it doesn't work

```js
uploadImage(name, imageBlob, token) {
  name += imageBlob.getName()
  let data = {
    'name': name,
    'key': token.key,
    'Filename': token.key,
    "success_action_status": "201",
    'AWSAccessKeyId': token.AWSAccessKeyId,
    'policy': token.policy,
    'signature': token.signature,
    'file': imageBlob
  }
  // let boundary = "---1011100000110100";
  // let rawdata = "";
  // for (let i in data) {
  //   rawdata += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  //   rawdata += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + i + "\"; \r\n\r\n" + data[i] + "\r\n";
  // }
  // rawdata += "--" + boundary + "--\r\n";
  // console.log(data.key)
  const url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/someExPath/'
  const headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data",
  }
  const opt = {
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    headers: headers,
    method: 'post',
    payload: data,
    followRedirects: true,
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  }
  let resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, opt)
  console.log(resp)
  console.log(resp.text)
  return name
}
```

Here's my python code

```
import requests
url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/samplePath/"
payload={
    'name': 'demo1.jpg',
    'key': 'tmp/sampleIds=/${filename}',
    'Filename': 'tmp/sampleIds=/${filename}',
    'success_action_status': '201',
    'AWSAccessKeyId': 'AKIAIDO4Q6WXHCGAMHIA',
    'policy': 'sample polici',
    'signature': 'sample sig'
}
files=[
  ('file',('demo1.jpg',open('demo1.jpg','rb'),'image/jpeg'))
]
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
```

The google app script returns: The body of your POST request is not well-formed multipart/form-data.
Python script even can't finish the request, it got a ConnectionError (check out the picture on the link below)

I've tried to pass it as a raw body but still doesn't work. The closest one I got is replacing the imageBlob by Utilities.base64Encode(imageBlob.getBytes()) then put it on the raw text body (check the comment code), I got the success code but when recheck it's an invalid image. Here is the doc that I found: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingHTTPPOST.html

You can check out my success Postman request and my python code here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Jb0-OctmXDy_rDD-Jk_N_QyrADHKamB2?usp=sharing

Thanks,

Comment: Start debugging it and share some details

Comment: When I saw your python script, it seems that an error occurs. Can you provide the correct python script as the text data? If you can do, please add it to your question. And can you provide the official document of the API you want to use?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks, I just added my script and link to the doc

Comment: @Cooper What details do you want to know more about? I added 2 picture capturing the values of variables right before UrlFetchApp.fetch can you check it out (google drive link)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I saw your python script. But I thought that your script might not correctly upload the file and metadata. Because `'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'` is used and, in this case, the boundary is not included. So I cannot understand about your current situation. I apologize for this. Can I ask you whether your python script worked correctly for achieving your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike Oh, I see, I thought the requests module will auto send the headers with a boundary when sending the request. I removed the 'content-type', it works and it works for google app script too. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike yes, I just did it, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the 'content-type' and it works for both python script and Google app script